# How can I copy and verify a file as I do the copy?

Tags: performance, disk, file-copy, io, integrity

(Yet another "copy and verify" question...)

I have a reasonable amount of data I want to copy between several HDDs, and I want to make absolutely sure the data is copied correctly.

My current copying approach has been fairly standard, copying then verifying (with sha256). I don't like the extra steps and time involved - 30-60 minutes to checksum is enough flow disruption that I do have to work harder making sure I haven't missed any steps and verified everything correctly.

So, I am specifically looking for a single-step copy-and-verify process.

**However, I don't want to reread the copied file out of the disk cache**, as that would negate the point of verification!!

I'm prepared to write my own tool for the job, if absolutely needed, but I would absolutely love to hear of someone who echoes the views here and who has already written a tool like what I'm describing.

On Linux I also know I can kill the disk cache with `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`. But doing this every few kilobytes or even megabytes is absolutely certain to kill I/O performance. This specific technique is also not generally portable, so I don't really want to file it away as my solution to this problem.

I know `fsync(file); fdatasync(file); fsync(dir); fdatasync(dir)` is probably a good starting point (overkill is good here), but I fear it'll kill sequential streaming throughput?

My current idea is to do the read/write copy while I also have the target file open 256MB behind where the read/write is up to, so it's *well* outside the range of the HDD's onboard controller and cache RAM, and then sequentially read and verify from that $copypoint-256MB location.

Could I do some fancy footwork with `O_SYNC | O_DIRECT` and get both acceptable speed *and* good guarantees that my read-back is getting data off the disk platters?

Or... is write-then-verify just the best way to deal with the very sub-optimal status quo that is "modern" operating systems, HDD controllers and good safe file I/O design? :/

Comment: Good point. Copying file-by-file.

Comment: Removed this as my 'answer', but doesn't `rsync` more or less do what you are looking for? You go into technical depths that are beyond me in this post so you might know better. HTH

Answer (score 0):

You could `cat` the source file and pipe it to `tee` to save it to the destination, and simultaneously pipe the output to `sha256sum`.  That way you don't have to re-read the source to compute its hash.  If you want to make sure the destination is re-read from the disk instead of cache, you can use `dd` with the `iflag=direct` option.